# Elixir, how running multiple processes under the supervision of a single Supervisor

Tags: process, elixir

There is a program of three modules. The **Print** module receives a number from the keyboard, passes it to another module, receives the response, and displays it on the screen. The **Proc1** and **Proc2** modules receive a number, perform calculations, and send the result back.

```
   defmodule Launch do
  @moduledoc """
  Documentation for `Launch`.
  """

  @doc """
  """
  def start() do
    children = [
      %{
        id: Print,
        start: {Print, :print, []}
      },
      %{
        id: Proc1,
        start: {Proc1, :proc1, []}
      },
      %{
        id: Proc2,
        start: {Proc2, :proc2, []}
      }
    ]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end

defmodule Print do
  def print() do
    num =
      IO.gets("Input number: ")
      |> String.trim()
      |> String.to_integer()

    if num >= 0 do
      send(Proc1, {self(), num})
    else
      send(Proc2, {self(), num})
    end

    receive do
      num -> IO.puts(num)
    after
      500 ->
        print()
    end
    print()
  end
end

defmodule Proc1 do
  def proc1() do
    receive do
      {pid, num} ->
        send(pid, 100/num)
        proc1()
      _e ->
        IO.puts("Error")
    end
  end
end

defmodule Proc2 do
  def proc2() do
    receive do
      {pid, num} ->
        send(pid, 1000/num)
        proc2()
      _e ->
        IO.puts("Error")
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to run all processes under the supervision of a single Supervisor. But there is a problem-only the first "child" is started, the other "children" are not started. In the example above, the **Print** process will start, but **Proc1** and **Proc2** will not start. How do I run all processes under one Supervisor? Important note: the Print process must get the addresses of the Proc1 and Proc2 processes for communication.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with the code you’ve posted.

#### Registered processes

To be able to use process name as [`Process.dest()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#t:dest/0) in a call to [`Kernel.send/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#send/2), one should start the [named process](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration).

#### [`Supervisor.start_link/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html?#start_link/2)

`Supervisor.start_link/2` expects a list of tuples, with modules *and* functions that immediately return, having the process started as a side effect. These functions are called, and there would not be any magic: if this is an infinitely recursive function, the execution flow would be deadlocked inside, waiting for the message in `receive/1`.

`Supervisor` performs some magic by automatically *monitoring* and *restarting* children for you, but it does nothing to spawn the separate processes. `GenServer` encapsulates this functionality and provides a handy way to not bother about spawning processes.

#### Solution

What you might do, is to spawn all three processes, manually monitor them, and react on `{:DOWN, ref, :process, pid, reason}` message *respawning* the died process. This is exactly what `Supervisor` effectively does under the hood for children.

`Launch`

```rb
defmodule Launch do
  def start() do
    proc1 = spawn(&Proc1.proc1/0)
    proc2 = spawn(&Proc2.proc2/0)
    print = spawn(fn -> Print.print(proc1, proc2) end)

    Process.monitor(proc1)
    Process.monitor(proc2)
    Process.monitor(print)

    receive do
      msg -> IO.inspect(msg)
    end
  end
end
```

`Print`

```rb
defmodule Print do
  def print(pid1, pid2) do
    num =
      IO.gets("Input number: ")
      |> String.trim()
      |> String.to_integer()

    if num >= 0 do
      send(pid1, {self(), num})
    else
      send(pid2, {self(), num})
    end

    receive do
      num -> IO.puts(num)
    end
    print(pid1, pid2)
  end
end
```

The other two modules are fine.

---

Here is how it will look like in `iex`

```rb
iex|1 ▶ c "/tmp/test.ex"
#⇒ [Launch, Print, Proc1, Proc2]
iex|2 ▶ Launch.start    
Input number: 10
10.0
Input number: 1000
0.1
Input number: a
#⇒ {:DOWN, #Reference<0.3632020665.3980394506.95298>,
#     :process, #PID<0.137.0>,
#        {:badarg,
#          [
#            {:erlang, :binary_to_integer, ["a"], []},
#            {Print, :print, 2, [file: '/tmp/test.ex', line: 22]}
#        ]}}
```

Now instead of printing this out, respawn the failed process, and you will get a bare implementation of the supervised intercommunicating processes. For `all_for_one` strategy that could be achieved with:

```rb
    receive do
      {:DOWN, _, _, _, _} ->
        Process.exit(print, :normal)
        Process.exit(proc1, :normal)
        Process.exit(proc2, :normal)

        start()
    end
```